# For loop being skipped c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have to find the sum of the geometric progression 1/3 + 1/9 + 1/27 ..... and I have to output the sum with setprecision 6.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int x = 1;
    float sum = 0;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        x *= 3;
        sum += (float)(1/x);
    }
    cout << fixed << setprecision(6);
    cout << "Sum of the geometric progression of the first " << n << " elements is " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program always outputs 0.000000 and when I try to add a test cout in the for loop, the program crashes.

Comment: So every `cout` statement inside the loop causes a crash?  What error message is given?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`(1/x)` is always 0, since both arguments are `int`. Use for example `(1.0  / x)` instead.

Comment: Classic mistake! We've all made it before, OP, so don't get down on yourself!

Comment: Exactly. Once you made it, you are *very* careful with floats. There is a nice saying that the good programmers are not those, who don't make mistakes. They're those, who made all of them once :)

Comment: I re-read the whole program, tried to do several tests and couldn't manage to find the problem and it was so simple.. thanks a lot for this! I will be careful in the future for sure with the floats. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `x` is an `int`,

```
(1/x)
```

is evaluated as integer division, which rounds down to zero.  This is then converted to `(float)`, but it's already zero.

You can use `(1 / (float) x)` to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
    sum += (float)(1/x);
```

to:

```
    sum += (1/(float)x);
```

You're doing integer division, which results in 0, and then casting that result to float.